# Why won't my Activity start?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to start an Activity with startActivityForResult, but I keep getting an ActivityNotFound exception, and I can't work out why. I've looked through the code multiple times, and it seems to be identical to some other, working code. Any suggestions?

The newNoteButton that starts the Activity:

```
    newNoteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Intent i = new Intent(Typy.this, TypyEdit.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, 1);
        }
    });
```

And the beginning of the TypyEdit Activity:

```
public class TypyEdit extends Activity {
private TextView mTitleText;
private TextView mBodyText;
private Long mRowId;
private NotesDbAdapter mDbHelper;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

Comment: If you looked in your logcat, you would notice that it lierally says "did you forget to include it in your manifest?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure the activity is included in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file like so

```
<activity android:name="TypyEdit" android:label="TypyEdit">
</activity>
```

Otherwise the activity will not be found.